# ReactJS - "ReferenceError: post is not defined" when passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a parameter to a component, but getting the `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: post is not defined` error when doing it - this is the critical line:

```
<NewPost onAddPost={(e) => this.addPost(post, e)}/>
```

I also tried this version,

```
<NewPost onAddPost={this.addPost(post)}/>
```

but with the same error message (but now, the whole page doesn't render at all).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/posts')
            .then(response => {
            this.setState({ posts: response.data, loading: false });
          });
    }

    addPost(post){
        console.log('in "addPost"');

        const oldPosts = this.state.posts;
        this.setState({posts: oldPosts.push(post)})
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NewPost onAddPost={(e) => this.addPost(post, e)}/>
        <Posts posts={this.state.posts} loading={this.state.loading} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App




class NewPost extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            namee: '',  
            description: '' 
        }

        this.handleChangeNamee = this.handleChangeNamee.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDescr = this.handleChangeDescr.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);   
    }

    handleChangeNamee(event) {      
      this.setState({
        namee: event.target.value
      });
    }
    handleChangeDescr(event) {      
      this.setState({
        description: event.target.value
      });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const form_data = {
      namee: this.state.namee,
      description: this.state.description
    };

    axios.post('/posts/testtt', { form_data })
      .then(res => {
        this.props.onAddPost(res.data);                  
      })
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <div style={{'marginBottom': '20px'}}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input name='namee' value={this.state.namee} onChange={this.handleChangeNamee}  />
          <input name='description' value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChangeDescr}  />
          <button onClick={this.handleItem}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
export default NewPost
```

I tried different variants of passing there the parameter, different ways of calling that function, but it still results with the **post is not defined** error. What am I missing here yet?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear - post isn't defined in your render event handler.

Currently you have two event handlers, one anonymous function defined in your render method (`onAddPost={(e) => this.addPost(post, e)}` - post isn't defined here, only e!) and another one in your class definition - `addPost(post) { ... }`.

I think you were meaning to do something like this:

```
<NewPost onAddPost={this.addPost} />
```

And bind your event handler to your component like so:

```
addPost = (post) => {
    console.log('in "addPost"');

    const oldPosts = this.state.posts;
    this.setState({posts: oldPosts.push(post)})
}
```

EDIT: Furthermore, you should avoid mutating the component state directly like you have done in this line: `this.setState({posts: oldPosts.push(post)})`. Instead you should create a new array instance like so: `this.setState({ posts: [...oldPosts, push] })`. React component state should always be treated as immutable - only ever updated by setState.

Comment: I was suggesting the same thing but also writing something about setting the state. `this.setState( prevState => ( { posts: [ ...prevState.posts, post] } ) )`

Comment: @devserkan thank you. But this way of update state, it will only the text (content) of the `post` to `state.posts`, it will not add there all the `post`s data, such as `post.id`, `post.created_at` etc, is that correct? Also, if there would be an error on the backend side - from some reason this `post` would not be added to the database, the code above would still add the `post` to `state.posts` (inconsistent data on front-end and back-end), is that correct?

Comment: No, it adds the post as a whole not only some text content. If there would be an error adding post on backend then you will handle it in your function. If there is success you will set the state, if error you do not. Also, your function does the same thing with this suggestion. You are setting the state without checking anything.

Comment: When I add the new post to the `state.posts`, I cannot print the `post.id` element nor any other attribute from the property.

Comment: We can't say anything if we don't see any good info. Just follow your data with some debugging like console.log. When you add a post what kind of data you are getting back from server? Is it ok or not. If yes, then what is the previous state before adding the post and what is the latest state?